# Suggest SQL query for given use case

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

**Original Table**

```
Id | Time | Status
------------------
1  |  5   |  T
1  |  6   |  F
2  |  3   |  F
1  |  2   |  F
2  |  4   |  T
3  |  7   |  F
2  |  3   |  T
3  |  1   |  F
4  |  7   |  H
4  |  6   |  S
4  |  5   |  F
4  |  4   |  T
5  |  5   |  S
5  |  6   |  F
```

**Expected Table**

```
Id | Time | Status
------------------
1  |  6   |  F
3  |  7   |  F 
4  |  5   |  F
```

I want all the distinct ids who have status as F but time should be maximum, if for any id status is T for given maximum time then that id should not be picked. Also only those ids should be picked who have at-least one T. For e.g 4 will not be picked at it doesn't have any 'T' as status.

Please help in writing the SQL query.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where t.status = 'F'
and exists (select 1 from tablename where id = t.id and status = 'T')
and not exists (
    select 1 
    from tablename
    where id = t.id and status in ('F', 'T') and time > t.time
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7vkUvZRcyXgFNDo6MswAxP/1).
Results:

```
| Id  | Time | Status |
| --- | ---- | ------ |
| 1   | 6    | F      |
| 4   | 5    | F      |
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, i have added one case in question please see if we can add that also it will be great help.  Added Case: only those ids should be picked who have at-least one T. For e.g 4 will not be picked at it doesn't have any 'T' as status.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below way -

```
select * from tablename t 
where time = (select max(time) from tablename t1 where t.id=t1.id and Status='F')
and Status='F'
```

Answer (score 0):

the following should work

```
select id,max(time) as time,status
  from table
where status='F'
group by id,status
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, max(time), status
from stuff s
where status = 'F'
and id not in (
    select id 
    from stuff s2
    where s2.id = s.id
    and s2.time > s.time
    and s2.status = 'T')
 group by id, status;
```

You can see the Fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fRY2h9UsdyRG6wJdM8TBpC/0).

As I understand it, you want to find the highest time for each ID (`max(time)`) where the status is F, but only if there isn't a later record where the status is 'T'. The sub query filters out records where there exists a later record where the status is T.

Comment: Thank you so much this helped, But one case is missing it is my bad i missed adding that, Status field can have other value other than T and F like it can have Null, S, T, P like any thing. I modified the question. But we will only care about T and F if time for F is greater than T then we need that customer id, other status time doesn't matter, Please suggest.

Comment: Thanks It works. Can we add one condition that selected id should have at-least one 'T'. I mean if a id has only F and other status but not T, then that id should not be selected.

Comment: Please update the question with all of your "just one more thing" requests - the point of Stack Overflow is to help people with similar questions, and that's much easier if they don't have to read a chain of comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH MAX_TIME_ID AS (
    SELECT
          ID
          ,MAX(TIME) AS MAX_TIME
    GROUP BY
          ID
)
SELECT
       O.*
FROM 
     ORIGINAL_TABLE O
INNER JOIN
     MAX_TIME_ID MAX
ON
    O.ID = MAX.ID
WHERE
    O.STATUS = 'F'
```

The CTE will find the max time for each ID and the inner join with the where clause on the status will select it only if the latest is 'F'.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
             row_number() over (partition by id order by time desc) as seqnum,
             sum(case when status = 'T' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id) as num_t
      from t
     ) t
where num_t > 0 and
      seqnum = 1 and status = 'F';
```

There is a another fun way to do this just with aggregation:

```
select id, max(time) as time, 'F' as status
from t
group by id
having sum(case when status = 'T' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       max(time) = max(case when status 'F' then time end);
```